# Random numbers in PyBee VOC

Tags: java, python, beeware

I'm trying to generate random numbers in Python code running on the JVM with PyBee's [VOC](https://pybee.org/project/projects/bridges/voc/) transpiler. For now, it looks like the Python `random` module isn't included, so how can I generate random numbers?

Here's the code I tried to transpile:

```
from random import randrange

print(randrange(5))
```

And here's the error when I run the class file in Java:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.python.java.Module (in module: Unnamed Module) cannot be cast to org.python.Callable (in module: Unnamed Module)
    at python.example.module$import(example.py:3)
    at python.example.main(example.py)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like my Python code can access all the standard Java libraries, so I just have to emulate the `random` module with Java.

```
from java.util import Random

r = Random()
randrange = r.nextInt

print(randrange(5))
```

If I want to test my code on Python before deploying to the JVM or Android, I can pass in the `randrange()` function as a parameter.